# Vue - vue2-google-maps load api key dynamically with props?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vue-component

How can I get access to the component props before the component will be rendered?
I would like to load the google maps api with the value of the passed prop.

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
import GmapCluster from 'vue2-google-maps/dist/components/cluster';
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
    load: {
        // Get here the prop apiKey
        key: '..........',
        libraries: 'places', in
    }
});
Vue.component('GmapCluster', GmapCluster);
export default {
    name: 'api',
    props: ['apiKey'],
    methods: {
    },
    created() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmn I've never heard about it and the [project page](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) is asking for contributers and this lib has more than 100 issues. So my suggestion is change the lib. I've made good experiences with https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on `beforeMount()` lifecycle hook.

```
     beforeMount() { 
        loadGmapApi({
            key: apiKeyProp
        });
      }
```